# How to store contact into an arraylist and insert into firebase? (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have managed to retrieve the contact list from the phone book
but right now i'm trying to store them in an array list (as shown below) and insert these contact data into firebase. I have no clue how to do it. Can someone enlighten me please? Thank you

Here is the code :

```
 List<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();

  List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

  names.add(name);

  num.add(phone);
```

Besides using `arraylist`, is there any other ways to store the `contactlist` into firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `HashMap`. This is the best way, because you can retrieve key and your object.

```
map.put("name_key", "name");
map.put("phone_key", "phone");
map.put("obj", new Object());
```

Using an `ArrayList` you will have keys like 0, 1, 2, 3, etc (index based). Using a `Map` you have your own keys (name_key, phone_key, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!